# Python script works as standalone but not with Crontab

Tags: python, cron

I have a simple code reading a csv file and loading each line into a JSON, which will be sent (Node Red).

```py
import os
import csv
import json
from time import sleep

TITLE = '/path/to/csv/file'

if(os.path.exists(TITLE)):
    with open(TITLE, 'r') as fp:
        fullLog = csv.reader(fp, delimiter = ',')

        for rowLog in fullLog:
            dictToSend = {"Val1" : rowLog[0],
                          "Val2" : rowLog[1],
                          "Val3" : rowLog[2],
                          }

            with open("data.json", "w") as outfile:
                json.dump(dictToSend, outfile)

            sleep(SLEEP_TIME_S)

        # Remove csv file once data sent.
        os.remove(TITLE)
```

This code works as expected when launched from the prompt. Permission for the JSON is set to 0o777.

Now, I want that to be executed every hour, on the 10-th minute. Then `crontab -e` :

```
10 *   * * *   /usr/bin/python3 /path/to/script/script.py
```

The script is launched (logged in journalctl), but nothing else happens.
The script is executable. I tried to create a debug file, showing what point of the code was reached, but the debug file isn't even created via Crontab. (Once again, no problem if launched from prompt)

Is there any restriction from Crontab ? Or did I just make a mistake so huge that I can't see it ?

Comment: Where is TITLE defined and what is its value?

Comment: Sorry I deleted a bit too much to make it not too large. TITLE is defined juste after the import lines

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that TITLE is always a full, absolute path (and not a relative path) ?

Comment: Yes full absolute. I just realized that json.data isn't ... Got to try it.

Comment: It is probably sending email of any error messages to your account on the system. You might want to redirect output to a logfile instead, so you can see what is going on. `10 * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /path/to/script/script.py >> /path/to/log_file 2>&1`

Comment: Ok, that's it, thanks @JacobIRR you made me see it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you encounter a problem like "this works here but not there", be sure to provide full absolute paths to files.

Comment: Yes with your comments I saw that "data.json" was relative, and it works now, thank you very much ! :)